# jQuery .text() function for expanding/contracting content area

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'm a bit stuck since my lack of knowledge in jQuery. Would appreciate any help. I have the following script to activate an expanding content area:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.moreExpand").click(function(){
       var myelement = $(this).attr("rel");
        $(myelement).slideToggle(function() {
            $("a.moreExpand").text(
              $(this).is(':visible') ? "LESS -" : "MORE +"
            );
          });
    });
});
```

My HTML (used on different places on the page):

```
<div class="moreExpandWrapp">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" rel="#aboutExpand" class="moreExpand">MORE <span class="plus">+</span></a>
    <div class="moreExpandContent" id="aboutExpand">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ...
    </div>
</div>
```

So far so good but once I expand/contract a content area all the texts (MORE/LESS text) are changed on the website. I've tried to target the script like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.moreExpand").click(function(){
       var myelement = $(this).attr("rel");
        $(myelement).slideToggle(function() {
            $("a.moreExpand", this).text(
              $(this).is(':visible') ? "LESS -" : "MORE +"
            );
          });
    });
});
```

So it's:  `$("a.moreExpand", this).text(`
But of course this won't help and replace the expanded content text instead of the link text. As far as I understand this is because the "$this" value is basically the whole toggled area not the button.

I would like to target the link copy instead of the expanding div but I'm not sure how can I use "$this" in this case (to target the first part of the function instead).

Would really appreciate your input on this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, *this* in JavaScript refers to your current scope.

inside the slideToggle callback, your scope refers to the "slided" element, so *this* === myElement.
You should keep your initial link using another var.

http://jsfiddle.net/t4CQt/

```
$("a.moreExpand").click(function(){
    var myLink = this,
        myelement = $(this).attr("rel");
    $(myelement).slideToggle('normal', function() {
        $(myLink).text(
            $(this).is(':visible') ? "MORE +" : "LESS -"
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you mate! This worked like a charm. My deepest appreciation for teaching me something new today.

Comment: All the pleasure is for me !